# java httprequest getting the body from the request

Tags: java, httprequest, apache-httpcomponents

I receive a post request from client. This request contains some json data which I want to part on the server side. I have created the server using httpcore. HttpRequestHandler is used for handling the request. Here is the code I thought would work

```
    HttpEntity entity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest)request).getEntity();

                    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

                    String str = inputStream.toString();

                    System.out.println("Post contents: " + str);*/
```

But I cant seem to find a way to get the body of the request using the HttpRequest object. How can I extract the body from the request object ? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `EntityUtils` and it's [toString](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) method:

```
String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

`getContent` returnes stream and you need to read all data from it manually using e.g. `BufferedReader`. But `EntityUtils` does it for you.
You can't use `toString` on stream, because it returns string representation of the object itself not it's data.
One more thing: AFAIK GET requests can't contain body so it seems you get POST request from client.

Answer (score 1):

... and for `MultipartEntity` use this:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        entity.writeTo(baos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String text = new String(baos.toByteArray());
```